# django cursor.execute("UPDATE...another model ) while saving current model form

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can i update another model using  cursor.execute("UPDATE..., while overriding  a model save method.

I  have 2 models

```
class Medication_List(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    medication_name=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, editable=True)
    medications_category = models.ForeignKey(Medication_Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, default=1)
    stock = models.DecimalField('Current Stock Level', max_digits=10,decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00)

class Medications_Bridge(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_details =models.ForeignKey(GeneralConsulting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medication_name_id = models.ForeignKey(Medication_List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    quantity_sold = Medications_Bridge.objects.raw("SELECT *,..... )
    .....
    quantity_received = New_stock_purchases.objects.raw("SELECT *,.....)

    for e in quantity_sold:
        if e.total_quantity_sold == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return e.total_quantity_sold

    for r in quantity_received:
        if r.total_quantity_received == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return r.total_quantity_received

    current_stock = r.total_quantity_received - e.total_quantity_sold



    cursor.execute("UPDATE medication_productsapp_medication_list SET stock = %s WHERE id = %s" % (current_stock, self.medication_name_id.id))
    transaction.set_dirty()
    transaction.commit()

    #i already tried transaction.commit_unless_managed() but it  didn't work

    super(Medications_Bridge, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when i save a record,nothing happens to  my cursor function. it  does not update the other model's  record.

Is such a  thing possible in django  or am i missing something.

I  know  i  can use signals but i have a circular import problem which limits me from using signals. The @receiver decorator keeps  giving me an error since Medications_Bridge(models.Model) already imports Medication_List(models.Model).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for raw SQLs? `stock` also doesn't appear to be in either of the models you show...

Comment: Fix the circular import problem instead.

Comment: @ Jon Clements sorry i  truncated my model when pasting it  here.  stock is a field in the first model. I  just  updated  it. Also i tried using the ORM but it  didn't work,

b= Medication_List.objects.get(...).update()

Comment: Also i tried using the ORM but it  didn't work

b= Medication_List.objects.get(...).update(...)
b.save()

Comment: Hard to tell as those `ForeignKeys` look almost like they should be OneToOne fields instead but... `self.medication_name_id.update(stock=current_stock)` could be what you're after... it's still unclear where `r.total_quantity_received - e.total_quantity_sold` are coming from...

Comment: r.total_quantity_received
- e.total_quantity_sold

are deduced  from  the queries above and they have a few if  statements but i omitted  that for brevity.

Comment: I see that... but I don't see how you get `r` or `e` anywhere... there's brevity and then there's missing out information necessary to get an answer :)

Comment: I have updated accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Those `return`s mean anything after won't execute... so you'll never get to your update query anyway... it also seems to imply that `Medications_Bridge` should have a `total_quantity_sold` attribute as well... I think you need to have a good look at how to create a [mcve] here and spend a bit more time on your question...

Comment: Thank  you so much i just removed the returns and it works. You have just schooled me.  Thank you, Master.